# Emacs - How to enter recursive edit mode when searching (C-r) instead of query-replace (M-%)?

Tags: emacs

I know how to enter recursive edit mode when query-replace (`M-%`), but sometimes I really don't want to modify the code instead I'm just in searching. Such as when I was reading code, and from one point I saw a function call, then I want to jump to the declaration of the fucntion (`C-r` Enter PageList::Init), when I have read the declaration I want to jump back to the calling of the function.

How to enter recursive edit mode when searching (not only when query-replace)?

Answer (score 3):

You can open a recursive edit while you are searching, if you use [**Isearch+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus).  Then, `C-x o` is bound during Isearch to command `isearchp-open-recursive-edit`:

> Invoke the editor command loop recursively, during Isearch.
>   Use `C-M-c` to end the recursive edit and resume searching from there.
>   Or use `abort-recursive-edit` to exit the recursive edit and cancel the previous search.

If you do not want to use **Isearch+** then this is all you need:

```el
(defun isearchp-open-recursive-edit ()
  "Invoke the editor command loop recursively, during Isearch.
Use `\\[exit-recursive-edit]' to end the recursive edit and resume searching from there.
Or use `abort-recursive-edit' to exit the recursive edit and cancel the previous search."
  (interactive)
  (with-isearch-suspended (recursive-edit))))

(define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-xo" 'isearchp-open-recursive-edit)
```

---

If you are asking about recursive editing *generally*, and not just during search, then the answer is command `recursive-edit`.  Just use `M-x recursive-edit` to open a recursive edit.  You can also bind this command to a key, of course.

(If the minibuffer is active, then you normally cannot use `M-x recursive-edit`.  In that case, bind a key in the minibuffer keymaps to `recursive-edit`. Or you can set option `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to non-`nil`, to be able to invoke `M-x recursive-edit` from a minibuffer.)

Answer (score 2):

You enter a recursive edit by calling `recursive-edit`, but there is no default binding which invokes this anywhere (and doing so arbitrarily might be hazardous).

In the case of `query-replace` there is some special-case handling which goes on when you type <kbd>C-r</kbd> which saves the current match data/point/mark/buffer/window configuration before entering the recursive edit, to ensure that it can restore things when you exit from it.

This need to wrap some situation-specific custom handling around calls to `recursive-edit` is very common to the existing use-cases, so there might not be a safe way to invoke it generally.

My guess is that custom handling would certainly also be needed to support it during an isearch, and I see no such facility.

Do note that Emacs pushes point to the mark ring when you begin an isearch; so for your specific use-case you would simply jump to & pop the mark with <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-SPC</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

From your workflow description, I'm not sure you really need recursive edit mode.

When you do a search in emacs, the current point is saved. On my system C-r is reverse isearch. When I hit it, I'm prompted for the search string and hit enter. This takes me to the first 'hit'. Hitting C-r againi takes me the next hit etc. Once you find the text you want, provided you don't hit enter, you can read the code and then hit C-g to cancel the search. This will jump your cursor back to the point where you started the search. This is fine provided you can see all the code you want to read on screen.

When you can't read all the code on screen and you need to move around in the buffer, you have to hit enter. Once you do this, you have lost the saved point and I suspect this is where you thought of using a recursive edit mode so that you can jump back once you finish. However, this won't work quite as you want because as soon as you hit enter to select the searched for string, you will come out of recursive mode and lose the saved point.

There are a couple of ways to fix this workflow to achieve what you want. In fact, your workflow is quite a common requirement. Because of this, many programming modes already have this functionality built in. Therefore, the first thing to do would be to ensure your mode doesn't already have this - it is probably called something like jump to definition or similar.

If your mode doesn't have this support, then you can get what you want by saving the point and then jumping back to it later. This is a really handy technique. All you need to do is C-SPACE twice. Then later, after moving the point to a new locaiton, you can just do a C-u C-SPACE to jump back to that point. From the emacs manual

> Instead of setting the mark in order to operate on a region, you
>   can also use it to “remember” a position in the buffer (by typing
>   ‘C-SPC C-SPC’), and later jump back there (by typing ‘C-u
>   C-SPC’).  *Note Mark Ring::, for details.